# Rails 4 Numericality Validation Not Throwing Error when Text Submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 form which saves nested associations, using the `simple_form` gem, and Postgres as the DBMS. One of the models saved in the form has 2 numeric input fields. The validation rules for these fields are as follows:

```
validates_numericality_of :field1, greater_than: 0, only_integer: true, allow_nil: true
validates_numericality_of :field2, allow_nil: true
```

If I type strings like "ten" or "thirty-five" or "$$$$$" into these fields, no validation errors occur, the form data is saved, and these fields are given a `nil` value. If I put a negative or decimal value into `field1`, the expected validation error is presented.

While this is unlikely to cause a tremendous amount of problems with the administrators using this form, I can't seem to explain why this happens. All other validations for this form work as expected.

Why are these values converted to `nil`? Why do I not get a non-numeric validation error? Is this just an annoying quirk to the `allow_nil` property?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_numericality_of), when you set `only_integer: true`, your value applying to the regular expression `/\A[+\-]?\d+\Z/`:

```
"123" =~ /\A[+\-]?\d+\Z/
#=> 0
"$$$$$" =~ /\A[+\-]?\d+\Z/
#=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does not explain why the second field, which does not have `only_integer`, exhibits the same exact behavior. I can type "string" into the second field, and it will just get set to `nil` and save, instead of failing to save and displaying an error.